# Spring MVC petición POST Multipart con JSON y binario

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, curl, swagger

Buenas!
Estoy teniendo problemas con JHipster para publicar un servicio rest que reciba mediante POST contenido binario y un objeto JSON.

El servicio se publica utilizando Spring de la siguiente forma:

```
public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<DocumentId> addDoc(@RequestPart(required = true) MultipartFile file, @RequestPart(required = false) String folder, @RequestPart(required = true) MetadataDoc metadata)
```

Ya en swagger al consultar la api se publica de forma incorrecta, marca el parámetro metadata como "undefined" y probando a hacer peticiones falla mostrando lo siguiente en el log:

```
2016-09-30 13:27:15.174  WARN 30451 --- [ XNIO-2 task-12] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported
2016-09-30 13:27:15.298 DEBUG 30451 --- [ XNIO-2 task-14] c.q.smartgov.aop.logging.LoggingAspect   : Enter: com.queres.smartgov.web.rest.errors.ExceptionTranslator.processRuntimeException() with argument[s] = [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported]
2016-09-30 13:27:15.298 DEBUG 30451 --- [ XNIO-2 task-14] c.q.smartgov.aop.logging.LoggingAspect   : Exit: com.queres.smartgov.web.rest.errors.ExceptionTranslator.processRuntimeException() with result = <500 Internal Server Error,com.queres.smartgov.web.rest.errors.ErrorVM@3d872331,{}>
```

Petición de ejemplo con CURL:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOLFJPTEVfVVNFUiIsImV4cCI6MTQ3Njk3NjY3N30.82FRMRSrrniEQcIhI6DtHEFf5ln3OSjS_6OWy-1d8h3Cp5MjRuxo04IuIxAX_WC8YJJ1QyLrq7loLUSQ8RV_Gw' -F file=@"result.txt" -F folder=folde -F metadata={"clave":"2","valor":"1"}  'http://127.0.0.1:8080/sd_api/api/almacen/addDoc'
```

¿Alguna idea? Porque según leo en la documentación de Spring debería ser factible:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart-forms-non-browsers

Comment: Al parecer el content type en tu método addDoc no es válido, en vez de la anotiación RequestPart podrías utilizar RequestParam (como en la documentación) el cual al parecer permitirá que hagas una petición con el content-type adecuado...

Comment: Actualmente estoy pasando como String el parámetro JSON, y haciendo la conversión "a mano". La solución que me indicas no cambia este escenario. Me gustaría poder declarar el parámetro como JSON, y que swagger lo reconozca como tal. Entiendo, según la documentación, que debería ser factible, lo explica en el punto 16.11.5 Handling a file upload request from programmatic clients.

Comment: Por curiosidad hermano, ¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: No conseguimos solventar el problema, optamos por recibir un String como parámetro y realizar las validaciones y conversiones nosotros "a mano".